# Non-in-memory olap for MySql

Tags: mysql, olap

I'm familiar with Mondrian. But I am looking for something like SSAS for MySql. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes reason. What's wrong with the question? I am just looking for a MySql compatible OLAP engine.

Comment: Good question, maybe Mondrian fans ;-). It's called a ROLAP (Relational) server, why you don't want a M-OLAP server ? Why not Mondrian? Why no SSAS ? .. that's a lot of why's

Comment: Thanks icCube for response.
I didn't know that SSAS supports MySql. I don't like Mondrian, because it processes cubes in memory. My database is very very large (thousands of millions records). I think it does not support such huge data.

Comment: Ok I see. Mondrian is a ROLAP server as well (IMHO can't handle this sizing). With this sizing you'll have to check the main vendors..

Comment: And who are the main vendors?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OLAP_Servers

Comment: It would be great if the closers of the question say what's wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a list of OLAP vendors here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OLAP_Servers.

For your sizing you should go for the big players (Oracle, IBM, Microsoft). Not sure how other solutions scale.